# google maps v3: geometry library not loaded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the `geometry` library; everything was fine but it stopped working. I'm not sure if I changed something on my side or it was on google side.

I'm loading the library with`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization,geometry&sensor=false"> </script>` after loading the basic gmaps script.

The initial libraries-loader js loads ok, but when it runs it does 'nothing'.

I debugged it and I found that the loader [1] includes the following code:

```
  if ('version' in google.maps) {
    return;
  }
```

(else, load the requested libraries)

In my current version, `google.maps.version` has "3.16.4".

Any hints on what's wrong here?

Thanks

[1] http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false

Comment: same here, want an answer

Comment: What happens if you load the release version (i.e. use v=3, so not the experimental version)?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, it started working again.
The same loader now skips the `if ('version' in google.maps) {` line and now everything works.

weird.

Comment: yea they rm that line I think